# MVC3, json data deserialization difference between request from C# and Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I made following controller method, which handles request data via JSON:

```
public virtual JsonResult ExecMethod([SomeRequestBind(RequestType="Method")] RequestObject request)
```

SomeRequestBind is an attribute which selects derived type from RequestObject, eg.

```
public class RequestObjectGetSettings : RequestObject
    {
        public new AuthLoginParams Auth { get; set; }
        public string Method <- this is derived from RequestObjects
    }
```

AuthLoginParams this object consist of two properties

```
    public class AuthLoginParams : AuthParams
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name {get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string Pass {get; set;}
    }
```

I made some test project (C#), which does the following:

```
var request1 = new
        {
            Auth = new { Name = "whatever", Pass = "some_pass" },
            Method = "GetSettings",
        };

using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "pl";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(request1));
                HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, serializer.Serialize(request1));
                Console.WriteLine(HtmlResult);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SomeError");
            }
        }
```

This way all works perfect, I mean object is properly initialized.

But. I tried the same from JavaScript:

```
                var message2 = {
                    Auth:{
                        Name:"whatever",
                        Pass:"goodPass"
                    },
                    Method:"GetSettings"
                };

                $("#message").text(JSON.stringify(message2));
                $.post("http://127.0.0.1:6661/ApiMethod",message2,{},"json");

                /*$.ajax({
                    url:"http://127.0.0.1:6661/ApiMethod",
                    type:"post",
                    data:message2,
                    ContentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json"
                    });
                */
```

When I pass message2 as object to post, on Controller it sets Method property, but properties from AuthLogin are null. When I try JSON.stringify it does not initialize nothing. As I took a look into Firebug, I observed post parameters are:

Auth[Name]  blabalbla

Auth[Pass]  xxxxxx

Method  GetSettings

And it seems, it comes to to controller into similar way, so it cannot read those properties for this object. So, it seems, that instead of something like:

```
{Auth:{Name:"aaa",Pass:"aaa"},Method:"GetSettings"}
```

It sends to server:

```
{Auth[Name]:"aaa",Auth[Pass]:"aaa",Method:"GetSettings"}
```

So, object is flattened instead of nesting.

How to send this object properly?

Answer (score 0):

try this for your jquery post

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:6661/ApiMethod",message2);
```

**edit**
you are calling $.post within jquery's `document.ready` event, correct?
also, try changing the name of the properties. That shouldn't make a difference, but it's worth a shot. try

```
{
    Authentication: {Name:'name', Password:'pwd'},
    Method: 'method name'
}
```

another option is to simply flatten the object. In this instance there is nothing to gain by having an Authorization model.

```
{
    Name:'name', 
    Password:'pwd',
    Method: 'method name'
}
```

Comment: I tried, it did not initialized too. I also took a look into string after JSON.serialize and serialize from C# - strings looks the same.
It seems, that for reason I do not know yet, nested Auth in Javascript is trasfered into Auth[Name].

Comment: `Auth[Name]` & `Auth.Name` are the same thing in js.

Comment: sorry for late answer. I wish to not flatten object - well... currently ;)
From what I observed is, that `$.ajax` or `$.post` sends data in form post matter (puts data in Request.Form property), and they really puts object into ~`"Auth[Name]":"aaa","Auth[Pass]"` which seems to be problem for binder (yes, for JS they are equal). Using C# JSON serialize to `"Auth":{"Name":"aaa","Pass":"aaa"}` which is OK for binder. The same result gaves `JSON.stringify` method.
As I needed this for test purposes I installed Poster extension to firefox which allows me to test this. Many thanks for help.